# Neural Network for File Decryption - Possible?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, encryption

I have already worked with Neural Networks before and know most basics about them. I especially have experience with regular Multi-Layer-Perceptrons. I was now asked by someone if the following is possible and somehow feel challenged to master the problem :)

---

**The Situation**

Let's assume I have a program that can encrypt and decrypt regular ASCII-Coded Files. I have no idea at all about the specific encryption method nor the key used. All I know is, that the program can reverse the encryption and thus read the original content.

**What I want?**

Now my question is: Do you think it is possible to train (some kind of) Neural Network which replicates the exact decryption-Algorithm with acceptable effort?

**My ideas and work so far**

I have not much of experience with encryption. Someone suggested just to assume AES encryption, so I could write a little program to batch-encrypt ASCII-Coded files. So this would cover the gathering of learning data for supervised learning. Using the encrypted files als input for the neural networks and the original files as training data I could train any net. But now I am stuck, how would you suggest to feed the input and output data to the Neural Network. So how many Input and Output-Neurons would you guys use?
Since I have no Idea what the encrypted files would look like, it might be the best idea to pass the data in binary form. But I can't just use thousands of input and output-neurons and pass all bits at the same time. Maybe recurrent networks and feed one bit after another? Also doesn't sound very effective.

Another problem is, that you can't decrypt partially - meaning you can't be roughly correct. You either got it right or not. To put it other words, in the end the net error has to be zero. From what I have experienced so far with ANN, this is nearly impossible to achieve for big networks. So is this problem solvable?

Comment: Well, to be honest, this seems totally impossible to me. At least the idea of cracking AES encrypted files. I'm basing this on two ideas. First of all, I doubt that a standard encryption algorithm that has survived three years of competition could be cracked with such an "old" technology. Then, the other point is that I doubt the "expresiveness" of NN. What I mean is that basically, you're looking for a function. This function belongs to a space of functions, that is, to my mind, highly unlikely to include the miraculous AES decryption function. As I've got no solid proof, I prefer a comment!

Comment: Neural networks are actually rather 'expressive' (in the sense that I think you mean it). A small two-layer network with only a few nodes can be trained to compute any boolean operator on two bits. If you allow that using just ANDs, ORs, NOTs, XORs etc it is clearly possible to compute the AES decruption function (after all our computers do it) then so must it be possible for NN to do the same if you provide that it has enough layers and nodes. So expressiveness is not the issue I think. Rather the question would be more about ...

Comment: ... the size and topology of the neural network, and how much training data and time/computation you'd need to make the backpropagation algorithm learn the function. Or even if the function is 'learnable' at all.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Another problem is, that you can't decrypt partially - meaning you can't be roughly correct. You either got it right or not.

That's exactly the problem. Neural Networks can approximate [continuous functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function), meaning that a small change in the input values causes a small change in the output value, while encryption functions/algorithm are designed to be as non-continuous as possible.

Comment: I guess this answer puts it in a nut shell. But I start getting interested in encryption, maybe I should do some reading on that topic. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You say that NNs can "approximate continuous functions" (and imply that they can only do so) - that's interesting. I tried to write a claim a bit like that, stating that NNs can only discover linear functions, but i realised that i didn't understand either NNs or boolean linearity with enough finesse to make it confidently. I'm glad that someone else did, though!

Comment: @Tom Anderson: single-layer perceptrons can only discover linear functions. More complex NNs exist for non-linear functions.

Comment: It is true that neural networks compute coninuous functions, yet thier output values can be interpreted as 'boolean' (i.e the output neurons have values 0..1. Properlt trained a value close to 1 can mean 'true' and value close to 0 'false'. And if somewhere in between it means 'I'm not quite so sure'. Neural networks are actually very good at classification problems, for example, and a classification function is decidedly *not* a continuous function.

Answer (score 3):

I think if that worked, people would be doing it. As far as i know, they aren't doing it.

Seriously, if you could just throw a lot of plaintext/ciphertext pairs at a neural network and construct a decrypter, then it would be a very effective known-plaintext or chosen-plaintext attack. Yet the attacks of that kind we have against current ciphers are not very effective at all. That means that either the entire open cryptographic community has missed the idea, or it doesn't work. I realise that this is far from a conclusive argument (it's effectively an argument from authority), but i would suggest it's indicative that this approach won't work.

Comment: Just want to point out that nobody did anything until somebody did something. I mean, someone is always the first. On rare occasion several people are all the first. Yesterday's amazing discoveries are Tomorrow's common knowledge.

Comment: I like Tim's Answer ;)
But Tom has a point: if it were possible, it would have been done before. Especially because it is a quite simple approach (only one being simpler would be Brute Force I guess).
Thanks for the oppinions. Maybe I'll consult a friend of mine who has more knowledge on encryption.

Comment: @Tim: True, of course. But i tend to think that if a lot of people have been doing things in an area for quite a while, it is unlikely that there are any simple but useful innovations left to make. It's not impossible, merely unlikely. I appreciate that this is an embarrassingly weak argument, particularly on a site like this.

Comment: @EliteTUM: I like Tim's answer too.

Comment: People are doing it, for example http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-34500-5_75, but the question is whether this is practical, or will ever be. Training NN takes a lot of time, training examples, and computational power. Intuitively, we should expect a decryption function to be very hard to learn (unpredictable mapping from input to output). If they were easy to learn by a NN, they would not be good encryption algos and probably be also easy to crack by other methods than NN.

Comment: @Kris I came here because I had the same idea EliteTum: 2ˆ11 plaintext-ciphertext pairs equals 2048 bytes, quite low isn't it? (read the abstract of the paper) And this renders the DES useless in 51 minutes, while 4096 bytes would take 72 minutes. IMO not bad at all, if you consider that you can guess the first exchanges or parts of the exchanges of a ciphered communication, just think HTTP, that whole GET / first packet, and parts of the answer might not be that hard to guess..

Comment: .. now, I might got that wrong, but why couldn't 'plaintext-ciphertext pairs' be pairs of bytes? ciphertext probably should have variable size..

Answer (score 1):

Say you have two keys A and B that translate ciphertext K into Pa and Pb respectively. Pa and Pb are both "correct" decryptions of ciphertext K. So if your neural network has only K as input, it has no means of actually predicting the correct answer. Most ways of encryption cracking involve looking at the result to if it looks like what you're after. For example, readable text is more likely to be the plaintext than apparently random junk. A neural network would need to be good at guessing if it got the right answer according to what the user would expect the contents to be, which could never be 100% correct.

---

However, neural networks can in theory learn any function. So if you have enough cyphertext/plaintext pairs *for a particular encryption key*, then a sufficiently complex neural network can learn to be exactly the decryption algorithm *for that particular key*.

Also regarding the continuous vs discrete problem, this is basically solved. The outputs have something like the sigmoid function so you just have to pick a threshold for 1 vs 0. .5 could work. With enough training you could in theory get the correct answer for 1 vs 0 100% of the time.

The above assumes that you have one network big enough to process the entire file at once. For arbitrarily sized ciphertext, you would probably need to do blocks at a time with an RNN, but I don't know if that still has the same "compute any function" properties as for a traditional network.

None of this is to say that such a solution is practically doable.